# Log in with Google account from the navbar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using default template ASP.NET MVC 5 project using Identity. I have successfully linked Google Oauth to my application and I'm able to log in, but I'm trying to modify the `navbar` to replace Log in link from `/Account/Login` to log in with Google directly from the `navbar` in the first home page.

my current _LoginPartial.cshtml

```
ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  @*  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>*@
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new partial view called _ExternalLogIn.cshtml. In _LogInPartial.cshtml just comment the code that you have written above in this question and call the partial view like this,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   @Html.Partial("_ExternalLogIn",new ExternalLoginListViewModel())
</ul>
```

See you might get error here for ExternalLoginListViewModel(). So you need to add the reference on the top of your page like this,

```
@using MyProject.Web.Models
```

Then in your _ExternalLogIn partial view write like this,

```
@model MyProject.Web.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security
@{
var loginProviders = 
Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
if (loginProviders.Count() != 0)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = 
    Model.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        foreach (AuthenticationDescription provider in loginProviders)
        {
            if (provider.AuthenticationType == "Facebook")
            {
             <li>
              <div class="form-group">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-social  
                 btn-gplus" name="provider"  
                  id="@provider.AuthenticationType" 
                   value="@provider.AuthenticationType" 
                     style="width:100%;text-align:left;border-
                      radius:0px;color:white">                              
                </button>
                </div>
              </li>
            }
        }
```

Change the css according to your requirement. Cheers.

Comment: I followed your steps and created new partial view and got error for ExternalLoginListViewModel() , When I insert @using MyProject.Web.Models in the top of _LoginPartial.cshtml VS highlight Web and says "using directive is unnecessary"

Comment: You need to include your project Web Models. Just change the MyProject to your project name. That's it.